Solve system of PDEs but not all functions are functions of all the variables
I am trying to solve a system of PDEs for 2 functions, c[t,x] and d[t]. d does not depend on the variable x. When I set up DSolve I get the following error:
" ... DSolve: The function d[t] was specified without dependence on all the independent variables. Each function must depend on all the independent variables."
Here is a code snippet:
DSolve[{
  D[c[t, x], t] == 
   D0 Exp[- EnL/(b*t + Ti)] D[c[t, x], {x, 2}] - 
    N1 D[d[t], t],
  D[d[t], t]  == 
   k01
      Exp[- En1t/(b*t + Ti)] c[t, x] (1 - d[t]) - 
    p01 Exp[- En1d/(b*t + Ti)] d[t],
  c[0, x] == C0,
  c[t, 0] == 0,
  D[c[t, x], x] == 0 /. x -> 0
  }, {c[t, x], d[t]}, {t, x}]

I then tried adding x to the function d, i.e., d[t] -> d[t,x] and then adding and additional equation,
D[d[t, x], x] == 0

But then I get a different error:
"There are fewer dependent variables than equations, so the system is 
overdetermined"

According to your second differential equation, d cannot be independent of x unless c is independent of x.

It seems that there are more equations than needed: four equations but only two variables (c(t, x) and d(t)).

Looking at c[0,x]==C0,c[t,0]==0 what happens when t==0,x==0 I assume C0!=0
